# Find solutions of a PDE (by substitution?)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> > Find the solutions of the PDE
> >     $$
> > 2v_{\xi\eta}+v_{\eta}=0.~~~~~(+)
> > $$

Hello, with this question I refer to [Transforming hyperbolic PDE into normal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527377/transforming-hyperbolic-pde-into-normal-form). I sum it up what happened there:

The original PDE was
$$
x^2u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}=0~~~~\text{in}~~~~\Omega:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>0,y>0\right\}~~~~~(++).
$$
Using the transformation
$$
\xi:=\ln(y/x),~~~~~\eta:=-\ln(xy),
$$
the PDE (++) was transformed into the PDE (+).

Now to find the solutions of (++), it is easier to find the solutions of (+). And that's what I want to do now:

I use 
$$
v_{\xi\eta}=v_{\eta\xi}
$$
to write
$$
2v_{\xi\eta}+v_{\xi}=2\cdot (v_{\xi})_{\eta}+v_{\xi}=0
$$
and then I substitute $z:=v_{\xi}$, getting the ODE
$$
z_{\eta}=-\frac{1}{2}z.
$$
Using "separation of the variables", I get
$$
z=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\eta+C_1(\xi)\right).
$$
Re-substituting, that means
$$
v_{\xi}=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\eta+C_1(\xi)\right)
$$
and integrating to $\xi$ gives me
$$
v(\xi,\eta)=\int_{\xi_0}^{\xi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\eta+C_1(\tau)\right)\, d\tau+C_2(\eta),
$$
which means for the original PDE (++) in my opinion, that the solutions are given by
$$
u(x,y)=\int_{z_0}^{\ln(y/x)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(xy)+C_1(\tau)\right)\, d\tau+C_2(-\ln(xy)).
$$

Can anybody tell me if this is right, i.e. if this are the right solutions?

With kind regards and thank for your help!

Comment: It is looking correct. I did not check with pen and paper.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a difference between looking correct and being correct, hehe.

Comment: I would like to verify that this are indeed solutions. But I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Try substituting. By hand it appears to be pain enough, so I suggest you get $u(x,y)$ and $(++)$ into Maple and check. The PDETools is fantastic. If it is not correct you can always recheck each step on Maple.